# pass data from tableview controller to view controller, but it appears null

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am creating segue in order to pass data from tableview controller to detail view controller [as shown in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuAZJ.png). My table cell
 has one UIImage and two UILabel and i would like to show three of them in detail view controller. However when i run the program, it appears null like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGkDA.png).

here is the segue of tableviewcontroller.m

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue:%@", segue.identifier);



    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TeamMembersSegue"]){

        NSIndexPath*indexPath = (NSIndexPath*)sender;

        ViewController2*vc = ((UINavigationController*)segue.destinationViewController).topViewController;

        vc.lawfirmname = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        vc.detail= [detail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        vc.lawyerimage = [thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
}
```

and the code of detailviewcontroller.h (view controller 2)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lawfirmname;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lawfirm;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *detail;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *detailtextview;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage*lawyerimage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;

@end
```

and detailviewcontroller.m (view controller 2)

```
#import "ViewController2.h"

    @interface ViewController2 ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController2


    @synthesize lawfirmname;
    @synthesize lawfirm;
    @synthesize detail;
    @synthesize detailtextview;
    @synthesize lawyerimage;
    @synthesize image;

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.lawfirm.text = self.lawfirmname;
        self.detailtextview.text = self.detail;
        self.image.image = self.lawyerimage;
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    /*
    #pragma mark - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    @end
```

I would be grateful if anyone has any solution. please inform me if you do not understand the question.

Comment: did you check if vc.lawfirmname and other properties are getting set up in yuor prepareForSegue?

Comment: Are you sure that the destination of the segue is the navigation controller?

Comment: you probably want to make sure that you're using selected row in the prepareForSegue

Comment: Why you are getting navigation controller? You need to get just destinationviewcontroller.

Comment: I would say to change this ViewController2 *vc = (ViewController2*)segue.destinationViewController; And log your [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; / [detail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; / [thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; to see if they are returning null value.

Comment: I have follow your method but it is still returning null

Answer (score 1):

> Use **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** to pass data from your tableview controller to details view controller. Example:-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.selectedRowModel = [self.someArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TeamMembersSegue" sender:self];
}
```

> then override **prepareForSegue** method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TeamMembersSegue"]){
        ViewController2 *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.selectedModel = self.selectedRowModel;
    }
}
```

> **Note:-** Create a common row model to represent your individual Row item. Model will store your image url and Image Description for each and every rows in the UITableView.

Comment: Thanks but do you know the method to create common row model?

Comment: Yes you can create a NSObject class that you can use as a Model.

Answer (score 0):

right now guys after i change the segue to

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showlawfirmdetail" sender:indexPath];
    }

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue:%@", segue.identifier);



    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showlawfirmdetail"]){

        NSIndexPath*indexPath = (NSIndexPath*)sender;

        ViewController2*vc = (ViewController2*)segue.destinationViewController;

        vc.lawfirmname = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        vc.detail= [detail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        vc.lawyerimage = [thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
}
```

it works partially. The remaining problem is i cannot add images in view controller 2 .It crashes. But if i remove the code `self.image.image = self.lawyerimage;` the apps run smoothly.

Comment: is lawyerimage a UIImage or UIImageView? Because if it's a UIImageView you should set: self.image.image = self.lawyerimage.image;

Comment: i have followed your instruction but there is still a green bug called Thread 1:breakpoint 1.1

Comment: lawyer image is a UIImage

Answer (score 0):

@Herman one more shot. I created a project and repeted all your code, just to see if I get something that I wasn't. So I didn't figure out what it's going wrong.

One thing I thought that can be possible, it's if you for some reason lost the IBOutlet connection or it is duplicate. Check it out, like in the image. See in the right corner there is just one Refering Outlet:

[image]

here it's my "TableViewController.h" code, the one thing I'm doing differently it's setting programmatically the NSStrings and UIImage:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TeamMembersSegue"]){
        ViewController2 *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.lawfirmname = @"Title";
        vc.detail = @"Detail here";
        vc.lawyerimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"print"];
    }

}
```

My "ViewController2.h" is the same as yours:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.lawfirm.text = self.lawfirmname;
    self.detailtextview.text = self.detail;
    self.image.image = self.lawyerimage;
}
```

And see, it's working fine:

[image]

Comment: yea it is very strange that it keeps bugging for imageview but I will try again

Comment: The problem is solved just want to know how to pass data of images from plist

Comment: every thing is ok now what a huge relieve.
i just put on my code:
vc.lawyerimage = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
instead of 
     vc.lawyerimage = [thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: Is there any issues yet? About the images you should use .xcassets

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution: 
replace

```
vc.lawyerimage = [thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

by

```
    vc.lawyerimage = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to declare three different strings in your second view controller and then pass data of the cell to these strings from your `prepareForSegue` method. After this fill your`IBOutlets` from these three strings in your `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` methods. This solved my problem similar to this. Hope this is helpful.